# Add button after clicking an list in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to add button "edit" and "delete" into list element after clicking on it.
Ive added 2 buttons to list element and set their display to none in class btnedit and btndelete:

```
function Add(){
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    let a = document.createElement('a');
    let button1 = document.createElement('button');
    let button2 = document.createElement('button');
    button1.innerHTML = "Edit";
    button2.innerHTML = "Delete";
    button1.setAttribute('class','BtnEdit');
    button2.setAttribute('class','BtnDelete');
    let input = document.getElementById('AddText').value;
    if (input.length < 3){
        alert('Must be longer than 3');
    }
    else if(input.length > 255){
        alert('Cant be longer than 255');
    }
    else {
        if (checkDate()!=null) {
            let date = checkDate();
            let t = document.createTextNode(`${input}   ${date}`);
            let test = new storage1(input,date);
            store(test);
            li.appendChild(a);
            a.appendChild(t);
            document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(li).appendChild(a);
            li.appendChild(button1);
            li.appendChild(button2);
        }
    }
```

In this function I change their background color when i click on list element:

```
    let list = document.querySelector('ul');
    list.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
        if (ev.target.tagName === 'LI') {
            ev.target.classList.toggle('checked');


        }
    }, false);
```

but i have no idea how to display buttons now

Comment: I was thinking of something like when list element is clicked change his button class from btnedit to btnedit1 where display isnt none

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the display:

```
button1.style.display = "inline";
```

or remove the class:

```
button1.classList.remove("BtnEdit");
```

Comment: Yeah but i have couple of lists elements and every of them have hidden buttons how do i know which one i clicked. Is there any way that i can get to children of my list from eventlistener and change it class?

Comment: Check this, it should help: https://jsfiddle.net/zmekqv8p/33/

Comment: I forgot you have 2 buttons. I have updated it to work on both: https://jsfiddle.net/zmekqv8p/41/

Comment: @fxtomek to toggle between using the class you can use the toggle method 
 https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_class.asp

or you use if-else statement. 
  https://jsfiddle.net/gy7L1dos/8/